# can't find decodeJpeg from tfjs-react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow.js

i want to tensorflow-js with react-native so i read document.
in there, write when image to tensor use decodeJpeg.
but can't find decodeJpeg

how to use decodeJpeg or find another way?

[

```js
....

import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import {decodeJpeg, fetch} from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
var jpeg = require('jpeg-js');


const App= () => {
  const [isTfready, setIsTfready] = useState(false);

  async function test() {
    await tf.ready();
    setIsTfready(true);
    
    const image = require('./answer.jpg');
    const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(image);
    const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true });
    const rawImageData = await response.arrayBuffer();
    

    const imageTensor = decodeJpeg(rawImageData);
.....
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nktVD.png)

Error TypeError: (0, _tfjsReactNative.decodeJpeg) is not a function. (In '(0, _tfjsReactNative.decodeJpeg)(rawImageData)', '(0, _tfjsReactNative.decodeJpeg)' is undefined)

Comment: Which version of @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native are you using ?

Comment: when i saw your comment, version is 0.1.2. so i switch version to 0.2.1. but it still don't find the function

Comment: oh i should do reset cache. thank you!